# How to fix x2go desktop, that does not resize contents, to fit in remote desktop window size

Tags: kde, remote-desktop, x2go

I transferred the KDE settings (ie contents of .kde) folder from an existing KDE to a new installed computer. Normally when I connect to a remote x2go, the windows are resizable, ie adjusting the remote desktop's windows size resize the contents, keeping stuff like the toolbars in place and shrinking the contained windows to match the screen size.

Before I transferred KDE settings the screen contents on the remote desktop were resizable, but after copying the settings from the existing computer the remote desktop is not resizing the contents. This means that I can't see the the bottom edge of the screen and the right edge of the screen.

The only reason I can think of is that because the settings were transferred from a fixed size desktop, the remote desktop is also fixed in size, thus making the window a view port onto a bigger screen.

Is there some way to fix this?